# Gutenberg moving core blocks between categories

Tags: block-editor

I've restricted a number of the default core Gutenberg blocks as many are unnecessary for my clients and will just add to the confusion of having the new editor.

The result of this is some core categories just have a single block inside them e.g. "formatting" only has a table.

Is it possible to edit/remove core block categories and move all blocks under a single category??

Limiting my blocks;

```
add_filter( 'allowed_block_types', 'res_allowed_block_types' );
function res_allowed_block_types( $allowed_blocks ) {
    return array(
        'core/image',
        'core/paragraph',
        'core/heading',
        'core/list',
        'core/quote',
        'core/cover-image',
        'core/file',
        'core/video',
        'core/table',
        'core/separator',
    );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Although I'm unsure on how to achieve this in php, within javascript you can change the category by hooking into the `blocks.registerBlockType` hook.

Here is a small example how it would work, although I'd recommend using lodash to deepClone the settings object to keep everything immutable.

```
const rearrangeBlockCategories = {
  'core/table': 'common',
};

wp.hooks.addFilter('blocks.registerBlockType', '[namespace]', (settings, name) => {
  if (rearrangeBlockCategories[name]) {
    settings.category = rearrangeBlockCategories[name];  
  }

  return settings;

});
```